# Como utilizar X-Http-Overriden-Method en Postman

Tags: java, spring, postman

Tengo una pregunta de PostMan más bien , resulta que en mi controlador tengo una petición GET en la que he de enviar un @RequestBod , me han pedido que tengo que hacer un POST y con el método

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<Test> example (@RequestBody Test test){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(test, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

El modelo Test solo tiene un atributo que es un String y se llama test.

```
public class Test {
    public String test;

    public Test(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

Necesitaría saber como enviar el RequestBody desde Postman  , actualmente lo hago así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algua ayuda ?

Comment: ¿Qué necesitas hacer: cambiar tu código java de GET a POST o enviar una petición GET desde Postman que incluya un body?

Comment: Perdona que haya tardado , si , necesito que esta petición incluya un body , por es primero envío un POST y luego utilizo el método X-HTTP-Method-Override.